# How to : Change Gnome Desktop icons to Ubuntu default icons

Tags: 14.04, gnome, icons

I just installed Gnome Desktop in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. I like it, but the icons looks a bit antique. I would like to change them to default Ubuntu icons ( Cinnamon allows it ). Can someone help me with it please ?

Comment: Install `gnome-tweak-tool`. It has options to change the icon theme.

Comment: can you please post an answer with a screenshot? I'm not near a system with it, or I'd have done it myself.

Answer (score 2):

As has been pointed out by [muru](https://askubuntu.com/users/158442/muru) this can be achieved by using the `gnome-tweak-tool`:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-tweak-tool
```

and then selecting the preferred icon theme:

[image]